# xmodmap not working for Alt-a

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap

So, I am trying to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to the right arrow. I followed 'xev and xmodmap' approach described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) and came up with this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 38 mod1 = Right"
```

which fails miserably: when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, `C` is printed. And if I simply press <kbd>A</kbd>, the cursor is moved to the right indeed.

Output from `xmodmap -pm` for mod1 is:

```
mod1  Alt_L (0x40), Meta_L (0xcd)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the man page says, or as `xmodmap -pke` will show:

> keycode NUMBER = KEYSYMNAME ...
>
> The list of keysyms is assigned to the indicated keycode (which
>   may be specified in decimal, hex or octal and can be determined
>   by running the xev  program).   Up  to  eight  keysyms  may  be
>   attached  to  a  key, however the last four are not used in any
>   major X server implementation.  The first keysym is  used  when
>   no  modifier  key  is pressed in conjunction with this key, the
>   second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key  is  used
>   with  this  key  and  the  fourth when both the Mode_switch and
>   Shift keys are used.

This means that

```
keycode 38 mod1 = ...
```

is illegal syntax.

Also, with `xkbd`, there can be more than four keysyms, and the additional keysyms behave as specified. For example, with the `level3(ralt_switch)` xkb-option active (which is the default on my distribution), the right alt key is mapped to `ISO3_Level_Shift`, and the 5th to 8th keysym describe the results when <kbd>RAlt</kbd> is additionally pressed. So in that case, you can do something like

```
keycode 38 = a A a A Right Right Right Right
```

or something similar, depending on what you want <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> etc. to produce.

Comment: After fixing .Xmodmap to have `keycode 38 = a A a A Right Right Right Right` and reloading, the mapping does not work and the same weird symbols as are printed as before. Shift+Alt+A produces the capital versions (and I also want to use only Alt without Shift). Any ideas?

Comment: A bit of investigation showed that the additional keysyms I see come from the `level3(ralt_shift)` xkb-option. So you need to fiddle with xkb (e.g. in `xorg.conf` by describing your keyboard), and then you can use xmodmap to change/specify those symbols.